# BeautifulSoup - Missing tag under tag

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

So, I want to get a text from "h1" tags. I'm using BeutifulSoup, and it works fine until there is no "h1" tag in the "article" tag, then I get the "**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'** error.
Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 

    "<article>
    <a href="http://something">
    </a>   (missing "h1")
    <a href="http://something">
    </a>
    </article>
    <article>
    <a href="http://something">
    </a>
    <a href="http://something">
       <h1>something</h1>
    </a>
    </article>
    <article>
    <a href="http://something">
    </a>
    <a href="http://something">
       <h1>something</h1>
   </a>
   </article>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

h1s = []

articles = soup.find_all("article")


for i in range(1,len(articles)):
    h1s.append(articles[i].h1.contents)
```

Those are the messages when I check the line with h1 tag and without.

```
type(articles[0].h1) 
<type 'NoneType'>
type(articles[1].h1)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just loop over `articles` , which is a list, and then use `find_all()` method to get all the `h1` inside the `a` tag and then add its `text` to h1s. Seems like that is what you want -

```
h1s = []
articles = soup.find_all("article")
for i in articles:
    for x in i.find_all('h1'):
            h1s.append(x.text)
```